# GPU not releasing resources on each epoch on tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, out-of-memory, gpu

I'm trying to implement this code: https://github.com/leehomyc/cyclegan-1
Everything is fine until my GPU run out of memory. My intuition tells me that in each epoch of the algorithm the GPU resources should be released, why this seems not to be the case? it is like its always accumulating GPU resources until it cannot allocate more then it throws the error. I have tried by limiting the GPU usage but it seems that it is not working either. Any information would be much appreciated. The image set I'm working on has a size of around 100 MB and my graphics card has 4 GB. Who can point out my error? Or if you need more information just tell me and I will get it for you. Thank you. Lastly, can a bad use of `tf.train.coordinator`, `tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)` or `tf.summary.FileWriter(self._output_dir)` cause this error?  Thank you

*ERROR*

```
Model/g_B/c6/Conv/weights:0
Model/g_B/c6/Conv/biases:0
2017-11-29 11:20:40.825993: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 
2017-11-29 11:20:40.826013: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-29 11:20:40.826017: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-29 11:20:40.826020: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-29 11:20:40.826040: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-29 11:20:40.955576: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-11-29 11:20:40.956141: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.62
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.56GiB
2017-11-29 11:20:40.956177: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-11-29 11:20:40.956188: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-11-29 11:20:40.956207: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
hereheeeheheheeheh
2017-11-29 11:20:40.958641: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
('In the epoch ', 0)
Saving image 0/20
Saving image 1/20
Saving image 2/20
Saving image 3/20
Saving image 4/20
Saving image 5/20
Saving image 6/20
Saving image 7/20
Saving image 8/20
Saving image 9/20
Saving image 10/20
Saving image 11/20
Saving image 12/20
Saving image 13/20
Saving image 14/20
Saving image 15/20
Saving image 16/20
Saving image 17/20
Saving image 18/20
Saving image 19/20
Processing batch 0/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 1/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 2/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.

**ETC**

Processing batch 194/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 195/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 196/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 197/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 198/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 199/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
('In the epoch ', 1)
Saving image 0/20
Saving image 1/20
Saving image 2/20
Saving image 3/20
Saving image 4/20
Saving image 5/20
Saving image 6/20
Saving image 7/20
Saving image 8/20
Saving image 9/20
Saving image 10/20
Saving image 11/20
Saving image 12/20
Saving image 13/20
Saving image 14/20
Saving image 15/20
Saving image 16/20
Saving image 17/20
Saving image 18/20
Saving image 19/20
Processing batch 0/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 1/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 2/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 3/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 4/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 5/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 6/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 7/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 8/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 9/200
Garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
('lets see:   ', None)
Processing batch 10/200
2017-11-29 11:25:06.741162: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 4294967296 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-11-29 11:25:06.742407: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 4294967296
2017-11-29 11:25:06.742620: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 3865470464 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-11-29 11:25:06.742630: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 3865470464
2017-11-29 11:25:06.742826: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 3478923264 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-11-29 11:25:06.742835: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 3478923264
Killed
```

*TRAINING METHOD CODE*

```
def train(self):
    """Training Function."""
    # Load Dataset from the dataset folder
    self.inputs = data_loader.load_data(
        self._dataset_name, self._size_before_crop,
        True, self._do_flipping)

    # Build the network
    self.model_setup()

    # Loss function calculations
    self.compute_losses()

    # Initializing the global variables
    init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(),
            tf.local_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    max_images = cyclegan_datasets.DATASET_TO_SIZES[self._dataset_name]
    #gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.5)

    print("hereheeeheheheeheh")
    config=tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True




    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        # Restore the model to run the model from last checkpoint
        if self._to_restore:
            chkpt_fname = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(self._checkpoint_dir)
            saver.restore(sess, chkpt_fname)

        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self._output_dir)

        if not os.path.exists(self._output_dir):
            os.makedirs(self._output_dir)

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        # Training Loop
        for epoch in range(sess.run(self.global_step), self._max_step):
            print("In the epoch ", epoch)
            saver.save(sess, os.path.join(
                self._output_dir, "cyclegan"), global_step=epoch)

            # Dealing with the learning rate as per the epoch number
            if epoch < 100:
                curr_lr = self._base_lr
            else:
                curr_lr = self._base_lr - \
                    self._base_lr * (epoch - 100) / 100

            self.save_images(sess, epoch)

            for i in range(0, max_images):
                print("Processing batch {}/{}".format(i, max_images))

                inputs = sess.run(self.inputs)

                # Optimizing the G_A network
                _, fake_B_temp, summary_str = sess.run(
                    [self.g_A_trainer,
                     self.fake_images_b,
                     self.g_A_loss_summ],
                    feed_dict={
                        self.input_a:
                            inputs['images_i'],
                        self.input_b:
                            inputs['images_j'],
                        self.learning_rate: curr_lr
                    }
                )
                writer.add_summary(summary_str, epoch * max_images + i)

                fake_B_temp1 = self.fake_image_pool(
                    self.num_fake_inputs, fake_B_temp, self.fake_images_B)

                # Optimizing the D_B network
                _, summary_str = sess.run(
                    [self.d_B_trainer, self.d_B_loss_summ],
                    feed_dict={
                        self.input_a:
                            inputs['images_i'],
                        self.input_b:
                            inputs['images_j'],
                        self.learning_rate: curr_lr,
                        self.fake_pool_B: fake_B_temp1
                    }
                )
                writer.add_summary(summary_str, epoch * max_images + i)

                # Optimizing the G_B network
                _, fake_A_temp, summary_str = sess.run(
                    [self.g_B_trainer,
                     self.fake_images_a,
                     self.g_B_loss_summ],
                    feed_dict={
                        self.input_a:
                            inputs['images_i'],
                        self.input_b:
                            inputs['images_j'],
                        self.learning_rate: curr_lr
                    }
                )
                writer.add_summary(summary_str, epoch * max_images + i)

                fake_A_temp1 = self.fake_image_pool(
                    self.num_fake_inputs, fake_A_temp, self.fake_images_A)

                # Optimizing the D_A network
                _, summary_str = sess.run(
                    [self.d_A_trainer, self.d_A_loss_summ],
                    feed_dict={
                        self.input_a:
                            inputs['images_i'],
                        self.input_b:
                            inputs['images_j'],
                        self.learning_rate: curr_lr,
                        self.fake_pool_A: fake_A_temp1
                    }
                )
                writer.add_summary(summary_str, epoch * max_images + i)

                writer.flush()
                collected = gc.collect()
                print("Garbage collector: collected %d objects." % (collected))
                print("lets see:   ",writer.flush())
                self.num_fake_inputs += 1

            sess.run(tf.assign(self.global_step, epoch + 1))

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
        writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

Comment: This might be of help: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1578

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried all those options.